# How can I make a yearly music chart in r? duplicate merging is not working

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, duplicates

I have a music ranking chart dataframe bb1

```
                                           title                 artist rank score
1                                  Thank U, Next          Ariana Grande    1   100
2                                     Without Me                 Halsey    2    99
3                All I Want For Christmas Is You           Mariah Carey    3    98
4                                     Sicko Mode           Travis Scott    4    97
5  Sunflower (Spider-Man: Into The Spider-Verse) Post Malone & Swae Lee    5    96
6                                     High Hopes    Panic! At The Disco    6    95
7                                        Happier  Marshmello & Bastille    7    94
8                               Jingle Bell Rock            Bobby Helms    8    93
9              Rockin' Around The Christmas Tree             Brenda Lee    9    92
10                       A Holly Jolly Christmas              Burl Ives   10    91
.
.
.
101                                    Without Me                                      Halsey    1   100
102                                 Thank U, Next                               Ariana Grande    2    99
103 Sunflower (Spider-Man: Into The Spider-Verse)                      Post Malone & Swae Lee    3    98
104                                    Sicko Mode                                Travis Scott    4    97
105                                    High Hopes                         Panic! At The Disco    5    96
106                                       Happier                       Marshmello & Bastille    6    95
107                                Girls Like You                  Maroon 5 Featuring Cardi B    7    94
108                                 Drip Too Hard                            Lil Baby & Gunna    8    93
109                                          ZEZE Kodak Black Featuring Travis Scott & Offset    9    92
110                                    Better Now                                 Post Malone   10    91
```

It's basically a compilation of weekly top songs.
In order to compile the 'scores' of each song to make a yearly top 10 chart
I wanted to add the merge the scores of each song and order the chart by descending score .
So I tried with the below code

```
for(i in 1:nrow(bb1)){
  if (((bb1[i,1]==bb1[i+1,1])&&(bb1[i,2]==bb1[i+1,2]))){
  bb1[i+1,4]<- (bb1[i,4]+bb1[i+1,4])
  bb1<-bb1[-c(i),]
  i=i+1
  }
}
bb1[order(-bb1$score),]
```

But it didn't work out like I wanted it to. Instead, this error pops up

```
Error in if (((bb1[i, 1] == bb1[i + 1, 1]) && (bb1[i, 2] == bb1[i + 1,  : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Can anyone help me out? Could there be other, more efficient ways to make the yearly chart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by using `dplyr` package. 
Here, I used the following example:

```r
letter = rep(c("A","B","C"),5)
score = sample(1:100,15)
df = data.frame(letter = letter, score = score)
```

What `df` looks like:

```r
> head(df)
  letter score
1      A    70
2      B    94
3      C    74
4      A    14
5      B    51
6      C    57
```

And using `dplyr`, we can compute the sum in each group:

```r
> df %>%
+   group_by(letter) %>%
+   summarise(sum_score = sum(score)) %>%
+   arrange(desc(sum_score))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  letter sum_score
  <fct>      <int>
1 C            329
2 B            288
3 A            265
```

So, with your datasets, you should replace `letter` by `title` (or a combination of `title` and `artist`).

Is it answering your question ?

Comment: I am not familiar with the group_by function, but when I try to use it, I get an error message that says "Error in UseMethod("group_by_") : 
  no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "character""

Comment: Also, how can I group by a combination of title and artist?

Comment: @viatmincode, I get the same error as you, but then I realized that I use too much the autocompletion from Rstudio, the right function is `group_by`, not `group_by_`.

Comment: the group_by function is returning the same error message :( should I install other packages?

Comment: did you install `dplyr` ? BTW, for grouping several groups, use `group_by(title, artist)`

Comment: yes I did! i think my console is recognizing 'group_by' as 'group_by_' :(

Comment: did you load `dplyr` using `library(dplyr)` ?

Comment: yes, and I am getting the message [> bb1 %>%
+ +UseMethod("group_by")(title)
Error in UseMethod("group_by") : 
  no applicable method for 'group_by' applied to an object of class "data.frame"] when I use the UseMethod syntax and the previous message when I use just [group_by]

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the output of `str(bb1)` and the code giving you this error (in order everybody can see it right away). If you try `bb1 %>% group_by(title, artist) %>% summarise(sum_score = sum(score)) %>% arrange(desc(sum_score))`, do you get the same error ?

Comment: I tried using consecutive piplines such as 'b1 %>% group_by(title, artist) %>% summarise(sum_score = sum(score)) %>% arrange(desc(sum_score))' which worked perfectly! Thank you for the kind answers. It seems like the error was caused by my os, I have seen some other instances of this problem on other forums  with no identified cause :/